# ImageResizer not working with virtual directories

Tags: imageresizer

I am using the ImageResizer successfully on other areas of my site where the images are being served from a folder within the application (both .jpg?width=100 & .jpg.ashx?width=100 work),  but when I try images from a virtual directory located on the local machine, I can only get resizing to work if I specify the image page using the "jpg.ashx?width=100" method.

The site's application pool is using NetworkService identity and the virtual folder has pass-through authentication enabled.  I've granted Modify permissions to NetworkService on the virtual folder too hoping that would help.

I am using IIS 7.5 in Classic Mode and the resizer diagnostics page doesn't show any issues.

Does anyone have ideas on why this may be happening? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Classic Mode requires the `.ashx` syntax, since ASP.NET doesn't see static file requests.

If you're seeing different behavior within the same site on the same host, then your virtual folder is probably *NOT* a virtual folder, it's likely a sub-application.

Comment: What confuses me is that it does seem to be intercepting the static requests everywhere else but the virtual folder, so it seem like it *should* work. Thanks for the response.

Comment: If you post the diagnostics page in a [Gist](http://gist.github.com) we might be able to shed more light on your problem.